# Trying to Read Live HTTP Headers Report from Firefox

Tags: javascript, forms, joomla, http-headers, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer an existing registration and payment system for a website.  The system is a 2 step process.  The first step is where the user submits their registration information.  Here is the output from Live HTTP Headers for the first form submission:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2lFlhEzILjR0V4WkJNSWMzWU0/edit?usp=sharing

In reviewing this step, I see that the user is being directed to a page that contains these http variables in the browser address:

```
plugin=cbpaidsubscriptions
&cbpgacctno=1
&cbppdtback=33d54252b823f27833aa451238663f83
&cbpbasket=178
&cbpshopuser=99fe7e456230069467dd397360ad951f
&result=payform
```

I need to understand exactly how these values are being passed through the form.  I am new to Live HTTP Headers so I am unclear as to how to read the output.

Ultimately, there must be some type of redirect script that is creating the hidden variables and then passing them through to the next form.  Here is the `script` code from the header of the form:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ney0XWUikFaOsRzywREWSP8LJNc7oi6VxikAgatuAcI/edit?usp=sharing

To sum up the question, my hope is to learn:

1) What scripting is taking place to redirect the user?

2) What do I need to do to recreate the unique variables to pass through my form?

3) Is there a tutorial on how to better understand live http headers?

Answer (score 3):

The extension generating the headers is called CBSUbs - Community Builder Paid Subscriptions - available from https://www.joomlapolis.com/cb-solutions/cbsubs

That extensions specifically manages subscriptions on websites, and is performing all the permissions management to say whether or not someone is subscribing, subscribed and allowed to access the content, subscribed but expired so can no longer access the content etc.

So those variables are all encoded in relation to the component. eg cbpshopuser is a key that identifies the user that is subscribing.

Unfortunately, I think the code behind CBSubs is encoded, so you won't be able to reverse engineer it directly as you would with other open source software.

I don't know much about live headers enough to assist you further, and can't tell exactly what it is you're trying to do - reverse engineering CBSubs is probably not the easiest option to look at. In this case, the functionality is provided by a Joomla Extension, and so looking at what the extension does rather than reinventing the wheel, is probably your best starting point.

Comment: Hi Patrick! CBSubs went GPL at the beginning of 2013 so it depends what version the OP is using whether the source is encoded or not.

Comment: @Patrick Jackson THank you both for the insight on this issue.  Yes, we are using CB Subs v 3.0 which is GPL.  Really the difficulty I am having is in trying to skip the invoice page, thus having a 2 step process.  I have a site which is successfully doing this with CB Subs 3.0, but we do not have admin access.  So I am trying to find the CB Triggers to produce the same effect.  Any suggestions on that?